# How to Get General Product Performance Report on Amazon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon MWS and i get all my product sales report. but I want to know if there is any way i can get sales report for any product ASIN which i am not selling. So That i can find  prospective product to sell.
--Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no way to view the performance of any products that you are not selling.

The only indicator is the Amazon SalesRank, which you can get over the [Product API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=products&group=products&version=latest)  (ItemLookup) or by Scraping the product page.

However, if you find a way, it would be neat if you post it here.

**UPDATE**: Thanks Jonathan, i updated the link. Jonathan pointed out that there's a new Product API in MWS. Use that, folks ;)

Comment: well there is one for price history http://uk.camelcamelcamel.com/ and this is another one for sales history i don't know if this guy is using his own products or not "http://www.ranktracer.com/account_workstation.php" for this website use username: demo@ranktracer.com and password: demopass

Comment: If you have access to MWS, you should use the new Products API. There is no (official) way to get historical sales info. https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html/180-2908086-7672115

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the dev documents I cant see a way to get the info for items you are not selling yourself.

It maybe worth looking through the Reports API docs, and playing with the scratch pad to find something you maybe able to use.

**Update:** As pointed out by Steve, the Products Advertising API. Refine product matching using sales rank on Page 8 may help.

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiMigrationGuide.*V140057720*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiMigrationGuide._V140057720_.pdf)

https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html

Comment: product advertising api should be the way, not MWS.